# An immutable person

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, immutability

I am trying to model person in OOPS using immutability.
I have created an object `bond` with age as 25. To change the age I have created a new object and returned it.

Is there any better way to change the age instead of passing all the values of object again? Is this a correct way to do?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


class Solution
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("TestMessage");      
        Person bond = new Person("bond",25,"100 High","Park St","10000","NewYork");
        System.out.println("The age of bond is "+bond.getAge());     
        //If I want to change age of John,create new object as the preson object is immutable.
        bond = bond.changeAge(50);
        System.out.println("New age of bond is "+bond.getAge());      

    }
}

//Immutable class....
//Rule 1:No setter..getters can be present
//Rule 2:Ensure that the class can’t be extended
//Rule 3:Make all fields final, To avoid problems in multithreaded env.
//Rule 4:Make all fields private
//Rule 5:Ensure exclusive access to any mutable components
final class Person
{
  private final String name;
  private final int age;
  private final String streetAddr1;
  private final String streetAddr2;
  private final String pinCode;
  private final String city;

  private int salary;
  private float bonusPercentage;

  public Person(String name,int age,String streetAddr1,String streetAddr2,String pinCode,String city)
  {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.streetAddr1 = streetAddr1;
    this.streetAddr2 = streetAddr2;
    this.pinCode = pinCode;
    this.city = city;
  }  
  public int getAge()
  {
    return this.age;
  }  

  public Person changeAge(int age)
  {
    return new Person(this.name,age,this.streetAddr1,this.streetAddr2,this.pinCode,this.city);
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to make the fields private and add getters, as they are already final. Unless, of course, you are reasonably sure the data won't *stay* a field. YAGNI applies.

Comment: @Deduplicator If there are no getters,how can I access the fields like age. If I want to find the age.

Comment: As I said, make it public and remove the getter.

Comment: @Deduplicator while that is true, a common practice in Java is to have private fields and getters, even if the fields are immutable.

Comment: @SimonForsberg: Hm, yes. I forgot to take many Java-programmers love for boilerplate and duplication sufficiently into account.

Comment: There is reason for using accessors over public final fields. This preserves the flexibility to change the class internal representation...

Comment: @Deduplicator if you return a complex type such as collection or a map, caller code could hold on to it and start messing its contents up even though it's a `final` field. Using a getter allows you to create a defensive (independent) copy. It also allows to add other stuff such us logging, explicit null safety etc. It would be nice if this boilerplate could be cut down by some syntax sugar like autoproperties in C#, still the need for this can be legit, it's not just a silly habit that Java devs have

Comment: @KonradMorawski: Yes, that's a problem for mutable types. Seeing none here though...

Comment: Why not store date of birth rather than age? Then you can write a method to compute age and never have to update age.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## General Review

#### Bad Practices

First, you import the whole package:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```

It is usually better practice to import specific classes. Also, I don't even see the use of any of these packages. Don't import what you don't need: it will affect performance.

#### Formatting

Your second class seems to have two-space indents. Java standard conventions suggests four-space indents.

Your spacing is also inconsistent. Consider:

> ```
> this.name=name;
> this.age=age;
> this.streetAddr1 = streetAddr1;
> this.streetAddr2 = streetAddr2;
> this.pinCode = pinCode;
> this.city = city;
> ```

You have some lines with spaces, some lines without. Choose a style, and stick with it. I suggest the spaces version, because it is easier to read...

Spacing here:

> ```
> public Person(String name,int age,String streetAddr1,String streetAddr2,String pinCode,String city)
> ```

and here:

> ```
> Person bond = new Person("bond",25,"100 High","Park St","10000","NewYork");
> ```

Put spaces after the commas; this will make it easier to read.

#### Naming

Usually, setters' method names begin with `set`. It is also suggested that it is so. `changeAge` should be `setAge`.

## Immutable Class Suggestions

> Is this a correct way to do?

Well, read on!

Immutable classes should not have any `set` methods. This is because an immutable class should only represent objects that *don't change*. If a person needs to be changed (not likely though), then the most obvious way to do so is to directly call the Constructor for a new Object, as a person with a different characteristic would not be the same person.

Comment: I think the problem with his change method is one of wording, not principle.  Suppose that the class has lots of fields, more than you want to type out into a constructor every time you want a new `Person` *just like* your old one, but with a different name?  Equally important case: suppose the class expands at some point, adding new fields; having a way to construct objects based on previously constructed objects saves you a lot of revisions in this case.

Comment: Having to reconstruct the object manually isn't the "most obvious way" to me. Immutable classes can have methods such as `withAge(int newAge)`, only these methods spawn an independent instance of the object (with a new age and the rest of data same as original). Case in point: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @konradmorawski exactly my point : )

Comment: @sqykly yeah, true, i actually read your comment and left a +1 after i wrote mine. FWIW, some languages, like JVM-compatible Kotlin, offer this thing out of the box, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html - under "Copying"

Comment: @sqykly As mentiond by you,how can I achieve the same in my class. I just need to change only field,it is better to send the details of all object and the new value to be changed.

Comment: @mc20 You're doing it right already, just naming it wrong.  `changeAge` makes it sound like the object itself will change.  `withAge`, as Konrad suggested above, is more clear.

Answer (score 6):

I usually create an inner class, Copier, which is responsible for copying all values from the original object to the new one. And the Copier class also provides setters that are used to override values. This approach is fairly similar the fluent builder API. A note that you have to firstly copy original values in the constructor in order to make sure all setters override them properly.

```
final class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;
    private final String streetAddr1;
    private final String streetAddr2;
    private final String pinCode;
    private final String city;

    private int salary;
    private float bonusPercentage;

    public Person(String name, int age, String streetAddr1, String streetAddr2, String pinCode, String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.streetAddr1 = streetAddr1;
        this.streetAddr2 = streetAddr2;
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public Person changeAge(int age) {
        return new Copier().withAge(age).copy();
    }

    private class Copier {
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private String streetAddr1;
        private String streetAddr2;
        private String pinCode;
        private String city;

        public Copier() {
            name = Person.this.name;
            age = Person.this.age;
            streetAddr1 = Person.this.streetAddr1;
            streetAddr2 = Person.this.streetAddr2;
            pinCode = Person.this.pinCode;
            city = Person.this.city;
        }

        public Copier withAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
            return this;
        }

        public Person copy() {
            return new Person(name, age, streetAddr1, streetAddr2, pinCode, city);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

This 2 attributes are not doing anything.

```
  private int salary;
  private float bonusPercentage;
```

They should be final as well. And you should probably want an overload for your constructor or some methods similar to your `changeAge`. If you plan to add more optional parameter in the future. Effective Java builder pattern may be of use.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any better way to change the age instead of passing all the values of object again? Is this a correct way to do?

There are two approaches that are typically used. Both are employed by the final class String, so we'll use that as our reference.

The first is to add a method to the final class which creates a new instance as a result of the method call. An example would be `String#concat(String)` which concatenates two `Strings` and returns a new immutable object with the result. This is the approach you came up with above.

The other is to create a new class called a `mutable peer`. `String` actually has two mutable peers, `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`. You supply the peer with  your immutable object, change the state of the peer, and then create a new immutable from it. As long as your API only takes your immutable class you can leverage the benefits of immutability, while clients can freely modify immutable peer instances. The Builder paradigm is often used as mutable peer.

Which approach is right? It depends. If you need a lot of flexibility to change the immutable, then go with a mutable per. If there are only a small number of mutation operations, it's cleaner and more convenient if they're directly on the object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the point by making **this** representation of a `Person` immutable.

Explanation: the age isn't something that is immutable by nature (as you already see you had to add a `changeAge` method). So when I read your code, *if I had no idea what a `Person` would be in real life*, I would think that when a Person has its age changed, it just disappears and let place to a new similar `Person` with only another age. Sounds weird...

So what ? I personnaly would modelize an immutable `Person` in this way:

```
final class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final LocalDate birthdate;
    private final String streetAddr1;
    private final String streetAddr2;
    private final String pinCode;
    private final String city;

    private int salary;
    private float bonusPercentage;

    public Person(String name, LocalDate birthdate, String streetAddr1, String streetAddr2, String pinCode,
            String city) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.streetAddr1 = streetAddr1;
        this.streetAddr2 = streetAddr2;
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return Period.between(birthdate, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person bond = new Person("James Bond", LocalDate.of(1930, Month.AUGUST, 25), "100 High", "Park St", "10000", "NewYork");
        System.out.println("The age of Bond is " + bond.getAge());

        // Yep, even if he also lives in the same place, has the same name, he's definitely not the same person as he's born 23 years later !
        Person anotherBond = new Person("James Bond", LocalDate.of(1953, Month.MAY, 16), "100 High", "Park St", "10000", "NewYork");
        System.out.println("Age of the other Bond is " + anotherBond.getAge());
    }
}
```

What did I do ? I just replaced the age by the `birthdate`. A birthdate is by definition immutable (because it's an instant that occured in the past and cannot be altered). Then I can automatically infer the age on demand.

Note: as the OP only asked for a review of the "age concept", I didn't alter the rest of `Person`.